# Pirate treasure on mars?

Tags: aliens, politics

In 2020 Scientists explore Mars and they discover a subterranean vault of alien origins. This giant vault is full with advanced technology, Weapons, Alien supermaterials and energy generators, and 10 big FTL-spaceships. The team of explorers and scientists reveal the information to all nations. What would happen to political relationships? Wich nation can claim the technology?

Comment: I just love how you have exactly 666 rep. Good luck with getting 6666 ;)

Comment: @Mołot :D Yes hehehe

Comment: « What would happen to political relationships? » is pretty much a canonical example of **too broad** on WB.  I suggest discussing it on [meta] to see if it can be improved.

Comment: Also, the title should reflect the question, not just some portion of the scenario involved.  E.g. “What would be the polical ramifications of …”

Comment: yeah, weird title. Just becuase of my quick reading, I read "pirate treasure maps". I was hoping for pirate treasure not alien items :( .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more or less what happened in the Stargate series.  Because the US was fronting the risk and expense they got all the tech they ran into.  A neat thing about Stargate and maybe relevant to this is that as I recall, the Navy kept all this stuff under wraps for a long time, even from the rest of the government.  It would be fun to have NASA do the same - or maybe even a corner of NASA.  Sort of like the Cassini group keeping the secret of Saturnian tech.

I think whomever put up the funds for the expedition would expect dibs on the spoils. Consider the space race: nations discovering new stuff (not as a pirate trove, but by inventing it) got first benefit with stuff then being licensed or sold over time.

I could imagine that if it were a private expedition the nation housing the company might elbow in in the name of national security and classify some of the goods.

An interesting spin on this might be with the explorers themselves.  One or more might mutiny and then with fabulous armaments, return to earth as conquerors and take over some nation.  Maybe they take over by force or maybe the nation is happy to capitulate to their new Martian overlords, hoping then to benefit from further conquest.  That would be a fine SF: a couple of rogue adventurers with super tech but the organizational capacity of the third world nation they have taken over vs the combined organizational ability of the rest of the world with their lower tech.

The last aspect of this SF scenario, and an important one, is the provenance of this alien tech.  When they power it up, will the owners know?  Will they come looking for it?  Might the owners still be on Mars somewhere?